# DB query in SQLite for multiple tables

Tags: sqlite, express, callback

I want to extract data from multiple SQlite tables in one query. Call the callback function with the (row) object, and then send to the client side. I've tried a few different ways and can only get one row returned.

```
let userIdentify = req.user
db.all("SELECT * FROM Table1 Where Name = ? UNION ALL SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE Name = ?)", (userIdentify, userIdentify), function(err, row) {
  if(row) {
    console.log(row)
    res.send({success : true, message : "Some message", information : row})
  }
})
```

When I run this, I get the row from table1 logged to the console and nothing for table2. I should also add that both tables have the same number of columns etc. They should each return a JS object with 19 key/value pairs.

Essentially I believe the query statement to be wrong, and it is only passing one data row into the callback function.

Please help.

Comment: Do each of the selects return rows when run separately?

Comment: yes,if I have multiple querys I can access them

Answer (score 0):

According to the [doc](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#databaserunsql-param--callback) (emphasis added):

> There are three ways of passing bind parameters: directly in the
>   function's arguments, **as an array**, and as an object for named
>   parameters.

It will work if you change `()` to `[]` around the parameter list like so:

`db.all("SELECT * FROM Table1 Where Name = ? UNION ALL SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE Name = ?)", [userIdentify, userIdentify], function(err, row) {`